# how th output the unequal sized list into file in R language

Tags: r, list, structure

data like this:

```
b <- list(
structure(c(2L, 11L, 52L, 63L, 123L), .Names = c("danazol",
"methyltestosterone", "ethinylestradiol", "methimazole", "ethionamide"
)), 
structure(c(6L, 9L, 16L, 49L, 66L, 67L), .Names = c("naproxen", "indomethacin",
"lornoxicam", "triazolam", "carbon tetrachloride", "allyl alcohol"))
)
```

I just want output every columns' .Names into every line of a file.
like this:

1st line:  "danazol", "methyltestosterone", "ethinylestradiol", "methimazole", "ethionamide"

2nd line: "naproxen", "indomethacin", "lornoxicam", "triazolam", "carbon tetrachloride", ...

Comment: There is an extra `,` after `"allyl alcohol"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
invisible(lapply(lapply(b, names), cat, '\n', file = '1.txt', append = TRUE))
```

Comment: More precise: `invisible(lapply(lapply(lapply(a, names),paste,"\t"), cat, '\n', file = 'cluster7.txt', append = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this...? If not, please rephrase your question to make clearer.

```
> unlist(sapply(b, names))
 [1] "danazol"              "methyltestosterone"   "ethinylestradiol"     "methimazole"         
 [5] "ethionamide"          "naproxen"             "indomethacin"         "lornoxicam"          
 [9] "triazolam"            "carbon tetrachloride" "allyl alcohol"
```

Or maybe looking for this...?

```
Names <- unlist(sapply(b, names))
paste(Names, collapse=", ")
[1] "danazol, methyltestosterone, ethinylestradiol, methimazole, ethionamide, naproxen, indomethacin, lornoxicam, triazolam, carbon tetrachloride, allyl alcohol"
```

I'm still confused, maybe this?

```
> lapply(sapply(b, names), paste, collapse=", ")
[[1]]
[1] "danazol, methyltestosterone, ethinylestradiol, methimazole, ethionamide"

[[2]]
[1] "naproxen, indomethacin, lornoxicam, triazolam, carbon tetrachloride, allyl alcohol"
```

Comment: Maybe I expressed unclearly. Every col in this list should be 1 line in output file but not print them all in 1 line.

Comment: output into file. And every list's sublist should be put into the corresponding line (1st col to 1st row; 2nd col to 2nd row). One of the answers is invisible(lapply(lapply(b, names), cat, '\n', file = '1.txt', append = TRUE))